# Unable to import 'sharp' into next.js project. "Module not found: Can't resolve 'child_process'"

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, npm-install, sharp

I am trying to import and use `sharp` in my Next.js project. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling `sharp` many times but every time I run `npm run dev`, this is the error I get.

```
./node_modules/detect-libc/lib/detect-libc.js:3:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'child_process'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/sharp/lib/utility.js
./node_modules/sharp/lib/index.js
./pages/index.js

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
```

For reference this is the code that is causing the error:

```
import sharp from "sharp";
```

---

I have also tried this code, with no success:

```
const sharp = require('sharp');
```

Every other dependency I have installed works except for `sharp`.

Comment: What version of node and sharp you are using??

Comment: did you import sharp in client side file? like in `pages/*.js` files ?

Comment: Node v14.19.2, Sharp "0.30.4". I am fairly new to using JS but I think its because I am trying to use sharp in a function I built on the client side and it can only be used on the server side. If this is the case, where should I define the function I need to use?

Comment: @bogdanoff Yea, I think that's the issue. I defined a function to process an image I pulled in from an api call. If I am unable to do this on the client side where should I do this? Sorry.. new to JS/ web dev

Comment: If that's case the you may want to use dynamic imports, since you have not shared the client side code it is difficult to guide you. But here is the link for dynamic imports https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import

Comment: @cyrus so you want to process an image which is located somewhere else right ?
then write an api in your backend for that. logic should be fetch that image (use axios or node-fetch) and it will return a buffer. Pass this buffer to `sharp` and process it & it will also return buffer  now use this buffer to respond  it to your client.
NOTE: you cant use `sharp` package in client side in anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There are issues specially if you use the M1 Macbook.

Read this comment below, or the others around:
https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/2794#issuecomment-880363027